# How can I access the certain indexes of string using the function?

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I was practicing and found some exercise on the internet and it says that I should copy `str2` to `str1`, perhaps the main problem is that I should copy only a certain index of that string (so from `str2[a]` to `str2[b]`). Therefore `A` and `B` should be entered so they reduce the range of copied indexes to `str1`. So here I used the function method to tackle this problem but something went wrong. So I don't get why function does not work, there must be a big mistake in my understanding or I did it all wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 50

void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b);

int main() {
    char str1[N], str2[N];
    int a, b;
    printf("please input str1:");
    gets(str1);
    printf("please input str2:");
    gets(str2);
    printf("please input a and b:");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("str2=%s, str1=%s", str2, str1);
    myfunction(str1, str2, a, b);
    return 0;
}

void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        str1 += str2[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `+=` to append to an array.

Comment: "Something went wrong" ... namely?

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`, it's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it has been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: [NEVER use gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6699433)

Comment: mkrieger1, my function doesn't work so I don't get where I did a mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Why do you take `str1` as input?

Comment: Please take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). The please [edit] the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your program:

- you should not use `gets()`
- `myfunction` just increments `str1` instead of copying characters.
- you should output the resulting string.

Here is modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N  50

void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b);

// safe replacement for gets()
char *mygets(char *buf, size_t n) {
    int c;
    size_t i;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
            if (i == 0)
                return NULL;
            break;
        }
        if (i + 1 < n)
            buf[i++] = c;
    }
    if (i < n) {
        buf[i] = '\0';
    }
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char str1[N], str2[N];
    int a, b;

    printf("please input str1: ");
    if (!mygets(str1, sizeof str1))
        return 1;
    printf("please input str2: ");
    if (!mygets(str2, sizeof str2))
        return 1;
    printf("please input a and b: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("str2=%s, str1=%s\n", str2, str1);
    myfunction(str1, str2, a, b);
    printf("str1=%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}

void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b) {
    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);
    int i, j;
    if (a < 0)
        a = 0;
    if (b > len2)
        b = len2;
    for (i = 0, j = a; j <= b; i++, j++) {
        str1[i] = str2[j];
    }
    if (i > len1) {
        /* do not truncate str1 but set the null terminator if needed */
        str1[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: MInor: Why not always null character terminate?  Maybe drop `if (i < n) {`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Since the program reads `str1`, presumably he only wants to replace part of it, not the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

> I should copy str2 to str1, perhaps the main problem is that I should
> copy only a certain index of that string (so from str2[a] to str2[b]).

It looks like you need to copy a part of one string in another character array starting from its initial position and as a result the character array shall also keep a string built from characters of the first string.

If so then the function should be declared like

```
char * myfunction( char str1[], const char str2[], size_t n );
```

that is one of parameters of your original function is redundand because using the pointer arithmetic you can always call the function like

```
myfunction( str1, str2 + a, b - a + 1 );
```

In your function implementation it seems there are typos.

```
void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        str1 += str2[i];
    }
}
```

For example the variable `j` is not used, And in this assignment statement

```
str1 += str2[i];
```

the left operand is a pointer. So you are just increasing the pointer itself without copying anything. For example if `str2[i]` contains the character `'A'` then the above statement looks like

```
str1 += 'A';
```

If there is used the ASCII character table then the statement is equivalent to

```
str1 += 65;
```

That is the address stored in the pointer `str1` is increased by `65` and will point beyond the destination array.

Also in main there is no great sense to input a string in the character array `str1` because as it is supposed it will be overwritten in the function.

Pay attention to the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard any more. Instead you should use the function `fgets`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written without using standard string functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 50

char * myfunction( char str1[], const char str2[], size_t n )
{
    char *p = str1;
    
    while ( *str2 && n-- )
    {
        *p++ = *str2++;
    }
    
    *p = '\0';
    
    return str1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char str1[N];
    char str2[N] = "Hello World!";
    
    puts( str2 );
    
    puts( myfunction( str1, str2 + 6, 6 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
World!
```

If you will change the function the following way

```
char * myfunction( char str1[], const char str2[], size_t n )
{
    char *p = str1;
    
    while ( *str2 && n )
    {
        *p++ = *str2++;
        --n;
    }
    
    while ( n-- ) *p++ = '\0';
    
    return str1;
}
```

then it will behave the same way as the standard string function `strncpy` declared in the header `<string.h>` which you should familiarize yourself with.

Comment: The last function indeed behaves like `strncpy`, with the same error prone and confusing semantics. The one thing the OP should learn about it is this: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @chqrlie Actually any C string function is error prone. You need correctly use standard string functions. And strncpy does not much differ from other string functions.

Answer (score 0):

`str1+=` is not how you assign to elements of `str1`. It simply increments the pointer variable `str1`, which is not useful here.

You can use two variables, one for the index in `str1` to assign to, and another for the index in `str2` to read from.

You also need to check for reaching the end of `str2`, and add a null terminator to `str1`.

```
void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b) {
    int i = 0, j = a;
    if (a >= 0 && a <= strlen(str2)) {
        for (; str2[j] && j <= b; i++, j++) {
            str1[i] = str2[j];
        }
    }
    str1[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, added validation of a and fixed i

Comment: Rather than repeatedly call `strlen()` and incur `O(len)` time, code could save the length and call `strlen()` only once.

Comment: It only calls `strlen()` once. It's in the `if`, not `for`.

Comment: And even if it were in `for`, a decent compiler would optimize it into a single call.

Comment: I am not sure if `myfunction("abc", "123", 1, 1)` should produce `"2"` or `"2bc"`. You chose  the first and I chose the second, which seems more consistent with the OP's `main()` function that reads `str1` from the user...

Comment: @chqrlie Good point, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Regarding *a decent compiler would optimize it into a single call*: I'm not sure you can count of that because `str1` and `str2` could point to the same string so the compiler would need to ensure that the code cannot set a null terminator inside `str2` via `str1`, which is not as obvious as assuming `str2` remains constant if no `char` object is modified in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying characters between the strings, the line:

```
str1 += str2[i];
```

just increments the pointer.

You probably want:

```
void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[], int a, int b) {
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
        str1[j] = str2[i];  // Copy the character in position i in str2 to position i in str1
        ++j;
    }
    str1[j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy Characters one by one from array of characters you can use for loop like:-

Considering a to be index of str1 where to paste and b be index of str2 from where to Paste.

This is not exact Solution but you can take help from this...

```
void myfunction(char str1[], char str2[],int a, int b)
{

    str1[a] = str2[b];

}
```

Comment: You have no loop.

Comment: They want to copy the characters in the range `str2[a]` through `str2[b]` into `str1`

Comment: we can do override, suppose str1 is ['a', 'b', 'c'] and str 2 is ['d', 'e', 'f'] then we can do str1[1] = str2[1]; this will change str1 to  ['a', 'e', 'c']

Comment: Barmar, yes this is exactly what I need the range..

Comment: @Karan If `a == 1` and `b == 2`, they want the result to be `str1` contains `"ef"`